# cheerio select element with multiple class separated with space

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have this html and want to select only the div with class 'image-container landscape'.

```html
<div class="image-container landscape">
        ...
</div>
...
<div class="image-container portrait">
        ...
</div>
```

Using `$(element).find('.image-container')` selects either one of the div, that comes first. But I only want the one with 'landscape'. I tried using `$(element).find('.image-container landscape')` but it doesn't work, maybe because it assumes `landscape` is a tag. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it would assume landscape was a tag.
You want either:

`[class="image-container landscape"]`

or

`.image-container.landscape`

This is just CSS3 for the record, you can probably read the full specs in less than an hour.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the second one and it works. And found the css3 selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: The second approach is usually better since it doesn't take ordering of the classes into consideration and allows extra classes. Also, less syntax. The first can be handy for cases where you need to test substrings on the attribute, though.